# How to do velocity concatenation?

Tags: apache, velocity, converters

I have three variables that are extracted from date: date, month and year separately. I want to concatenate them into one variable and then convert into a date format.
I am trying like this

```
#set( $str = "$date_curr1$month_curr1$year_curr1" )
#set( $dateFormated = $dateTool.toDate("ddMMyyyy", $str))
```

Comment: what you are getting? any error you got?

Comment: DateTool will not work this way you should send as a date .

Answer (score 3):

There are several mistake in your code [DateTool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/DateTool.html) dateformat wrong Your format should be `dd-MM-yyyy` not `ddMMyyyy`.

Velocity string concatenation we need to use always variables and set in velocity always `#set` 
I have added this map

```
contextMap.put("dateTool",new DateTool());
contextMap.put("date_curr1","14");
contextMap.put("month_curr1","06");
contextMap.put("year_curr1","2017");
```

And velocity file

```
#set($concat ="-")
#set( $str = "$date_curr1$concat$month_curr1$concat$year_curr1 ")
$str
#set( $dateFormated = $dateTool.toDate("dd-MM-yyyy",$str))
$dateFormated
```

Output

```
14-06-2017
```